# Bugzilla's "Request System": do other issue tracking tools have it?

Tags: bugzilla, issue-tracking, youtrack

I've used Bugzilla for many years and one of my favourite features is the "request system" (http://www.bugzilla.org/features/#rs), also known as "flags".  The issue can flagged (?) to a user;  the user can then accept the request (+) or deny it (-).

I am in the process of re-evaluating our issue tracking tools and I can't seem to find anything other than Bugzilla that has this feature.

So I am wondering:

- *Does* any other product offer similar functionality?
- And if not, then is there a way to mimic it (using labels or custom fields or something)?

Your advice is appreciated (FYI:  I am currently leaning towards YouTrack).

---

Alex V. asked for more details about Bugzilla's request system functionality.  Here's an example:

An arbitrary list of flags can be created in the admin interface.  When editing an issue, they are listed in a row, here's an example:

[image: A sample list of unset flags]

Next, someone can set the flag and ask for a followup.  The screen shot shows me (dcherk) setting the DJiNNInput flag for john@doe.com:

[image: A sample flag requested]

Note that the same flag can be requested multiple times (not shown).

Later, john@doe.com might act on the flag in some way and mark the request as accepted:

[image: A sample flag, accepted]

Alternatively, john@doe.com might not be able to accept the request.  In that case, he would deny it:

[image: A sample flag, denied]

Needless to say, all these changes are tracked in the issue history, and can be searched and reported on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:

This is what we ended up doing in YouTrack:

Created two `user[*]` fields:

- Input Requesting (i.e. the person requesting input)
- Input Requested (i.e. the user whose input is needed)

The users can always set these fields manually, but we also added the following workflow rules to speed things up:

**Rule 1, relates changes to the two field:**

```
rule Input Requested 

when Input Requested.changed { 
  if (Input Requested.isEmpty) { 
    Input Requesting.clear; 
  } else { 
    Input Requesting.add(loggedInUser); 
  } 
}
```

**Rule 2, closed issues do not need any more input:**

```
rule Clear Input Requests When Issue Becomes Closed 

when State.becomes({Closed}) { 
  Input Requested.clear; 
  Input Requesting.clear; 
}
```

**Rule 3, @mentioning sets the fields; replying clears the fields:**

```
rule Input Requested via @mention 

when comments.added.isNotEmpty { 
  var separators = " `!#%^&*()=[]{}:;'\"\\|,<>/?\n\r\t"; 
  var mentionedUsers = ""; 

  var myComment = comments.added.first; 
  var originalText = myComment.text; 
  var text = " " + originalText.lowerCase + " "; 

  var username = ""; 
  var user = loggedInUser; 
  var index = -1; 

  index = text.indexOf("@", opts); 

  while (index != -1) { 
    index = index + 1; 
    username = ""; 

    var nextSymbol = text.substring(index, index + 1); 
    while (!separators.contains(nextSymbol, opts)) { 
      username = username + nextSymbol; 
      index = index + 1; 
      nextSymbol = text.substring(index, index + 1); 
    } 

    if (username.endsWith(".", opts)) { 
      username = username.substringOfLength(username.length - 1, opts); 
    } 

    debug("Extracted @username: |" + username + "|"); 
    if (username.isNotEmpty) { 
      user = project.getUser(username); 

      if (user != null && !mentionedUsers.contains("@" + user.login + ",", ignoreCase) && (user.isInGroup(permittedGroup.name) || permittedGroup == null || user == reporter) && (myComment.permittedGroup == null || user.isInGroup(myComment.permittedGroup.name))) { 

        if (Input Requesting.contains(user)) { 
          Input Requested.remove(loggedInUser); 
          if (Input Requested.isEmpty) { 
            Input Requesting.clear; 
          } 
        } else { 
          Input Requested.add(user); 
          Input Requesting.add(loggedInUser); 
        } 

        mentionedUsers = mentionedUsers + "@" + user.login + ","; 
      } 
    } 

    text = text.substringRelative("@" + username, pos: after); 
    index = text.indexOf("@", opts); 
  } 
}
```

Hope that helps anyone along the way.

Answer (score 0):

In YouTrack there's no such functionality. What you can do, however, is you can Star the issue for a user as if the if the user did it themselves. They will then receive a notification about it and can either leave the star on the issue, or remove it.
Don't know exactly how those flags work in Bugzilla, so it's is probably not a complete replacement of that feature. If you elaborate on the desired behaviour, I'll let you know how (if possible) to completely mimic it.

Comment: I've updated the question with an example.  See above.

Comment: Ok, if I get all this stuff right, you can mimic these flags in YouTrack the following way. (I'll asume you have there's one flag. In case there're many, the steps might need to be repeated for each one, but that depends on your processes).
* Add a field of type User to your project. The field will represent a user who the flag is assigned to.
* Add a field of State type. It will contain the status of the flag (initial/accepted/rejected).
* Add a workflow that will only allow the user from the first field to modify the second one.

Comment: That's a great idea.  I will try it out in our sandbox,